# Update table and then delete row if not set it

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have two tables:

```
users
-------
-id *
-name
- id_detail

details
-------
-id
-name
-id_user *

* FK
```

then i insert into the those tables the follow json:

```
{id: 1, name, 'jhon',details: [
                                {id: 11, name: 'detail 1'},
                                {id: 22, name: 'detail 2'},
                                {id: 33, name: 'detail 3'}
                              ]
}
```

Now i edited the json and i want to update those tables:

```
{id: 1, name, 'jhon',details: [
                                {id: 11, name: 'detail 1'},
                                {id: 22, name: 'detail 2'}
                              ]
}
```

i update the first level of the json, {id: 1, name, 'jhon'} with the table 'users' then the second level.
{id: 11, name: 'detail 1'}, {id: 22, name: 'detail 2'} with table 'details'
But how i can delete (deleted from json) {id: 33, name: 'detail 3'} ?? which is the best query to do that?

Comment: `DELETE FROM somelinkedtable WHERE user_id = 1 AND id NOT IN (11,22);`  or something, hard to tell without your actual tables/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is your problem, but if you need to update the two MySQL tables from Json, the best way is to follow these steps:

1. Read your `users.id` from Json, store it in a variable call it `$userid`
2. Delete from `details` `where id_user = $userid`
3. Delete from `users`  `where id = $userid`
4. Insert Json data into `users` and `details` tables